# Running a hook when ggplot creates a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, hook

I want to run a function every time ggplot creates a plot.

Using the traditional R graphics, this was doable by adding a "hook" like this:

```
setHook('plot.new', my_function)
```

From them on, every time a plot was created `my_function` was executed.

Is there a way to achieve the same with ggplot?

Comment: You could also wrap the plot within your own function and run the custom function within it whenever the plot was done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use a hook, you can use `setHook('grid.newpage', my_function)`

For example,

```
my_function = function() cat('function ran\n')
setHook('grid.newpage', my_function)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_point()
```

Note, this will also establish the hook for other functions/packages that use grid graphics, so use with caution/awareness.

Probably better is to make a new print method for ggplot objects:

```
print.ggplot = function(x, ...) {
  my_function()
  ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x, ...)
}
```